# How to test if a folder can be deleted

Tags: windows, lua, com, luacom

I am writing a Lua function to delete a folder using Luacom in Windows (version 7 onwards and I can't dictate the version). The folder path is specified in UTF-8 and **will** contain non-ASCII characters, so os.remove, io.whatever, Penlight and lfs will not work. So far I have (using Luacom to access the Windows com model):

```
function delFolder(sPath, bForce)
  --sPath is a fully specified folder path
  --bForce is a Boolean indicating whether the folder should be
  --deleted even if it contains read-only files
  require('luacom')
  fso = luacom.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  --code in here to test that the folder exists,
  --and return an error if it does not
  fso:DeleteFolder(sPath, bForce)
end
```

My problem is that, if bForce = false, and the folder is effectively read-only, the operation errors out.  I need to be able to test for this situation and return an error instead of attempting the operation.

One possibility is to manipulate the Luacom error handling not to abort on error, and test the last error after the operation:

```
luacom.config.abort_on_error = false
luacom.config.last_error = nil
fso:DeleteFolder(sPath, bForce)
if luacom.config.last_error then
  --return error indicating that the folder cannot be deleted
end
```

but is there a simpler way, using the com model or some other alternative available in Lua?

Reference for [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/deletefolder-method)

Comment: Scripting.FileSystemObject is just a (old) Windows Shell provided utility. What you could try on recent versions of Windows is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page which enables implicit UTF-8 support for ANSI versions of Windows APIs. I've not tested it in your lua case

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, that approach could work but I've been told it's not thread-safe. Correct me please if I'm wrong. Also I need to cater for all versions of Windows from 7 onwards (post amended to include that info)

Comment: Don't see the relation with threading, but indeed, it won't work before Windows 10 version 1903. I guess the best is to write a native lua extension (https://kevinboone.me/lualib.html?i=1) and call proper Windows UNICODE API (DeleteFileW) instead of ANSI (DeleteFileA) ones.